# How can I use the world "neighboring " and associate it with a country?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions, adjectives, idiomatic-language

I'm trying to say the following context, but I'm not sure which structure I can go with ??

Different Versions of the context :

1- I'm just reciting USA'S neighboring countries.

2-  I'm just reciting the neighboring countries to USA.

3-  I'm just reciting  neighboring countries of USA.

4-  I'm just reciting   countries neighboring USA.

Comment: If you "recite" something then you have learned a list, typically by rote.  You might recite the alphabet, the times tables, or a verse from the Bible or Koran.  You would typically *list* the neighbouring countries of the US rather than reciting them.  Recitation would imply that you had learned the list by heart and that it had to come in a particular fixed order.

Answer (score 1):

> 1- I'm just reciting USA'S neighboring countries.

Correct, except it should be "the USA's", as it is "*the* United States of America's".

> Have a question about the USA? Learn where to find answers to the most requested facts about the United States of America.

[source](https://www.usa.gov/about-the-us)

> 2- I'm just reciting the neighboring countries to USA.

"the neighboring countries *of the* USA"

> 3- I'm just reciting neighboring countries of USA.

This is fine (again, needs "the"), but is subtly different in meaning.  If you say "reciting the neighboring countries" then you're saying that you're reciting *all* of them, whereas "reciting neighboring countries" could be just *some* of them.

> 4- I'm just reciting countries neighboring USA.

This is also correct (if used with "*the* USA"), in the sense of "reciting countries that neighbour the USA".  It would be equivalent to sentence 3 in that sense (and sentences 1 and 2 would be equivalent if corrected).